# jQuery UI accordion action on timeOut

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use [jQuery UI accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) on a page to display different content sections. At the end when a link is clicked an AJAX request is sent and if the result returns success I need to:

- Collapse all jQuery UI Accordion sections, and
- Expand the first one

I thought of doing it with setTimeout but I'm sure there's a better way. I am also not sure how to "fake" a click on the accordion's tabs, but I think this is the way to go, because I actually want to show the sequence of events: one is being collapsed and the other one expanded.

When the accordion is open it looks like this:

```
<h3 id="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" class="ui-accordion-header 
ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-accordion-header-active 
ui-state-active ui-corner-top" role="tab" 
aria-controls="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1" aria-selected="true" tabindex="0">
last tab</h3>

<div id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1" class="ui-accordion-content 
ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" 
style="display: block;" aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" 
role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">content</div>
```

and when it is collapsed:

```
<h3 id="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" class="ui-accordion-header 
ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-corner-all" 
role="tab" aria-controls="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1" 
aria-selected="false" tabindex="0">last tab</h3>

<div id="ui-accordion-accordion-panel-1" class="ui-accordion-content 
ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" style="display: none;" 
aria-labelledby="ui-accordion-accordion-header-1" role="tabpanel" 
aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true">content</div>
```

Comment: Post your jQuery too. A link to a jsFiddle would also help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the jQuery UI Accordion API you can open the first section by invoking

```
$(".accordionSelector").accordion("option", "active", 0);
```

You can take a look at the API documentation at http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active

Comment: I think this will work on page load, but I do not re-load page on click, but rather use AJAX.

Comment: I tried it and it works at any point, not just on page load. It means you can execute this command when the AJAX ends successfully. And this is the official way to do it by the API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function collapseAll() {
    $('.ui-accordion-header').parent().each(function() {
        $(this).accordion({
            active: false,
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: myData,
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status == "OK") {
            collapseAll();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: It seem to hide the content but the header remains "open" with the icon pointing down and the bottom border missing...

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the solution, in case someone's interested:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#accordion h3:last-child").click();
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
    $("#accordion h3:first-child").click();
}, 1000);
```